# Kafka in Kubernetes Cluster- How can services in the K8S cluster be accessed using SASL and services outside the K8S cluster be accessed using SSL

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I want to deploy the Kafka cluster on the Kubernetes environment and have the services within the Kubernetes cluster connect to Kafka in SASL_PLAINTEXT mode and the services outside the Kubernetes cluster connect to Kafka in SASL_SSL mode.  However, I found that after setting this up, external services cannot connect to Kafka. Does Kafka not allow internal services to connect to external services differently?  My Kafka version is 2.3.1 and I would be grateful if you could answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, yes. You'd need to setup two `advertised.listeners` and `listeners` on the brokers with a protocol of and SSL for one set and SASL_SSL / SASL_PLAINTEXT for the other.

It's kubernetes network policies that control how cluster access happens, not only Kafka, but also, you'll need a NodePort or Ingress for any external app to reach services within the cluster. The Strimzi operator covers both, by the way